# devDependencies and peerDependencies are the same?

Tags: npm, dependencies, yarnpkg, peer-dependencies

Pardon my ignorance, if I am developing a library, should (some of) my `peerDependencies` be duplicated in my `devDependencies`? I'm thinking yes, right?

Example:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.0", <- needed for consuming the transpiled library
    "sugar-date": "2.0.6",
    "yup": "0.27.0"
  },  
  "devDependencies": {
    "sugar-date": "2.0.6", <- this is actually a "dependency"
    "yup": "0.27.0", <- this is actually a "dependency"
    ...
   }
```

Because this is a library, if I put them as dependencies, then in the project that consumes them, they will install their own node_modules when the project might already contain these dependencies, resulting in duplicated code - so I put them in `peerDependencies` to avoid this. But now I can't develop (e.g. write tests), so I have to put them in `devDependencies`.

Is this correct? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Googlefu has shown me that this is still a point of contention: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1503

Comment: This doesn't solve the question asked, but `npm install` usually avoids duplicate dependency installation (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm), so you might be okay using regular dependencies.